# C++ equivalent of .net Stream?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

What is the base class of all the streams in C++?

Also what is the equivalent of MemoryStream in C++?

Answer (score 7):

There are several shared base classes for streams: `std::ios::ios_base` is the ultimate superclass, but there are also `ios`, `istream`, `ostream`, and `iostream` for different types of functionality. `istream&` and `ostream&` are what you most commonly see used as polymorphic parameter types.

Here's a pretty picture: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/

I'm not a .Net person, so I don't know how MemoryStream is typically used, but `std::stringstream` probably serves at least some of the same purposes. If that doesn't do what you need, I think you're left messing about with streambufs.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a pure C++ solution then Steve's answer is the right direction.

If you happen to be running on Windows and don't mind using COM then the IStream interface is a close match to System.IO.Stream. CreateStreamOnHGlobal will result in an IStream built on a memory buffer much like MemoryStream.

Answer (score 0):

One base class is `std::ios::ios_base`, but all of the stream-related classes are templates (which caused me a lot of grief back on 2001, converting some really clever pre-standard C++ code).  This allows streams to be used with `char`, `wchar_t`, and any other type somebody wants to use as a character.  It's not necessarily possible to refer to a single base class in C++, since the language has multiple inheritance and the library uses it, but it looks like `ios_base` qualifies in this case, although it provides format functionality and not I/O.

I don't know how .NET streams work on a low-level basis, but C++ streams are fairly complicated underneath the surface.

If what you're looking for is something like `MemoryStream`, it looks to me like `stringstream` might fill the bill, or possibly the deprecated `strstream` (deprecated, but still in the latest draft of the C++0x standard I've seen), which IIRC allow you to attach a stream to a selected area of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at System.IO.Stream's documentation on MSDN, it seems to be closer to a C++ streambuf than to a C++ stream.

In the C++ IOStreams library, there are two layers:

- the basic_streambuf is the lower layer, taking care of the actual I/O, and only dealing with sequences of "characters". There are various implementations, depending on what the I/O is made with. For example base_filebuf reads from and writes to files, basic_stringbuf reads from and writes to an in-memory string.
- the stream (basic_istream for input, basic_ostream for output), which contains a basic_streambuf. The stream's role is formatting (i.e., transforming between values of other types and the sequence of "characters" handled by the streambuf). It does not do the actual I/O itself; it delegates it to the streambuf.

What blurs the issue is that the streams, in addition to their formatting interface, also expose more or less directly their streambuf's functionality, so a stream *can* be used to do non-formatted I/O. For output, for example, basic_ostream has a number of operator<< for formatted output, but it also has the "put" and "write" members allowing to (more or less) bypass the stream and directly write to the contained streambuf.